# Awking out lines after match with getline

Tags: bash, awk, getline

Whats wrong with this?

```
for i in {0..16};do 
awk '/foo/ {while (getline > 0); print $0}' ${array[$i]} >> lines.txt;done
```

I thought "The expression "getline > 0" will be true as long as getline successfully reads an input line. When it gets to the end-of-file, getline returns 0 and the loop is exited."

I want to print out every line after the one containing "foo". I get something similar to what I want with the lines above but its not correct.

Comment: How precisely does your output differ from what you expect? An example would be good.

Comment: Why not just `sed -n -e '/foo/,$p'`?

Comment: It only prints out the last line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the semicolon.

```
awk '/foo/ { while(getline > 0) { print }}'
```

Or

```
awk 'p; /foo/{p=1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your command:

```
awk '/foo/ {while (getline > 0); print $0}'
```

I think it will **only** print the last line of the input file. since you have a ";" after while(..), so it made the while(..) fetch each line (without printing) till the end, and then print $0 will print it (the last line) out.

btw, there would be easier solution for your job. e.g.

```
awk '/foo/{o=1}o'
```

Comment: That will print the `foo`  line, move the `o` to the front or add `next`.